# Mysql Select rows to the sum of

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum

I have a table with the following info:

```
id |      Item ID     | stock_package_id | amount | price
0  |        775       |         1        |   16   |  0.22
1  |        758       |         2        |   10   |  0.28
2  |        775       |         3        |   10   |  0.30
3  |        774       |         4        |   10   |  0.25
4  |        775       |         5        |   10   |  0.10
5  |        775       |         6        |   10   |  0.55
```

My issue is i'm trying to create a query (simple as possible as this table will be left joined with a few other tables) that will allow me to enter an amount:

e.g.

I want 22 of Item_Id 775 selecting from the cheapest price first.

So what I would want returned is:

```
id |      Item ID     | stock_package_id | amount | price
4  |        775       |         5        |   10   |  0.10
0  |        775       |         1        |   12   |  0.22 - this is only 12 as we only want 22 total
```

a pesudo example:

select from stock_table until the sum of `amount` is equal to or greater than input number (22) order by price

Is this possible to do with MySql?

Comment: Hmmm.. "having sum" allows you set conditions on a sum.. and "order by ... ascending" can let you order amount.

Comment: Can you amend the "what I would want returned" to what you really want? I can't see a SUM(..)'d column with 22 there

Comment: @Martin That's kinda the point. It should show me only rows upto 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE table1
(`id` int, `Item_ID` int, `stock_package_id` int, `amount` int, `price` float);

 INSERT INTO table1
(`id`, `Item_ID`, `stock_package_id`, `amount`, `price`)
 VALUES
(0, 775, 1, 16, 0.22),
(1, 758, 2, 10, 0.28),
(2, 775, 3, 10, 0.30),
(3, 774, 4, 10, 0.25),
(4, 775, 5, 10, 0.10),
(5, 775, 6, 10, 0.55);
```

Setting amount to get:

```
SET @var_amount = 22;
```

Selecting amount:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT table1.*, if ((@var_amount := @var_amount - amount) > 0, amount, amount +  @var_amount) as buy_amount
FROM table1
WHERE Item_ID = 775
ORDER BY price ASC
) AS tmp 
WHERE buy_amount > 0
```

Result:

```
id  Item_ID stock_package_id    amount  price   buy_amount
4   775 5                       10      0.1     10
0   775 1                       16      0.22    12
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to use `ORDER BY` clause to sort the records based on `price` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE Item_ID = 775
ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 22;
```

if you want to fetch records until `sum(price)` becomes `value`(22) then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name, (SELECT @var_price := 0) a
WHERE Item_ID = 775 AND
      (@var_price := @var_price + price) <= 22
ORDER BY price ASC;
```

Comment: OP wants to SUM `amount` to be equal to 22

Comment: Wouldn't this limit to 22 rows not the sum of amount is == 22?

Comment: this seems a lot closer. It will work though i will next an extra stage to remove the "excess" stock found, but your example does seem to return only the lines I actually need.

Comment: just in testing it should be until amount == 22 not price. Tried changing the + price to + amount but with no luck

Comment: For anyone coming along 9 years later, the second code block in this answer indeed does the right thing, where it sums up to 22. The first block does what these previous comments are talking about, where it selects 22 rows instead.