# Summing multiple row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table name request and the request has the following fields

```
id mem_id amount status rtype
1   11     200     0     ph
2   12     200     0     ph
3   13     400     0     ph
4   14     200     0     ph
5   15     300     0     ph
```

what i wanted to do with this table is if a user insert another data and the rtype = gh and amount = 600 i want mysql to pick from the request table and sum the amount in order to get the new requested amount which is 600 like a peer to peer donation

The result can  look like

```
id mem_id amount status rtype
1   11     200     0     ph
2   12     200     0     ph
4   14     200     0     ph
```

or

```
id mem_id amount status rtype
1   11     200     0     ph
3   13     400     0     ph
```

i have this query but it returns an empty result from my phpmyadmin

```
SELECT id, mem_id, SUM(amount), status, rtype FROM tbl_request WHERE rtype = 'ph' AND status = 0 AND amount = 6000 GROUP BY id;
```

please any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you are grouping by the `id` column, as that column appears to be a primary key for your table.

Comment: amount = 6000 in the WHERE clause will always look if the value '6000' is present in the field 'amount' not the sum

Comment: If you have only few records in the request table(may be 20 records), then you can fetch all of the records into php array/object & do your calculations

Comment: Actually am new to mysql and i may not really know when and how to use the where clause but with most of the tutorial  i saw online use the where clause and please can you point me to the right direction on how do it in the array format @sadasivam

Comment: i remove the group by id from my query and it still return  null result

Answer (score 0):

You can do cumulative sum using a mysql variable.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT @var:=600) a,
    (SELECT 
        tbl_request.*,
            if((@var:=@var - amount) > 0, amount, amount + @var) as my_amount
    FROM
        tbl_request 
    WHERE
        rtype = 'ph' AND status = 0
    ORDER BY amount ASC) AS b
WHERE
    my_amount > 0
```

[image: Result]

from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935359/6124896

Comment: i implemented the your code and it works but what if variable i wanted to use is not static like am using am getting the variable from a user which may be any figure if i capture the variable with php how will i replace it in the your sql command with the @var:=600